# C++ - Allocate an unsigned char buffer and then fill it with a string

Tags: c++, arrays, unsigned-char

I am realively new to `C++` so please forgive me if this is a naive question - but I'm stuck on finding an answer.

I am trying to create an `unsigned char` array of size `1024` which I have done with the following code:

```
unsigned char *r_record = new unsigned char[1024]();
```

Now I have an `std::string` variable:

```
std::string hw = "Hello Word";
```

And I would like to populate the `r_record` with `hw` (i.e., 'Hello World') starting at the `10'th` byte.

**How can I place `hw` into `r_record`?**

So in effect, my r_record data would look like (where the `.`'s are empty):

```
[.........Hello World......and so on]
```

Comment: [**`std::copy(hw.begin(), hw.end(), r_record + 10);`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy)

Comment: @0x499602D2: Why are you posting answers as bold comments?

Comment: You can't help being new, but you sure can help [using new](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500313/c-why-should-new-be-used-as-little-as-possible). If you don't want `std::string` for some reason, use `std::vector`. If this is homework, enlist in a better class.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Should I delete because I can't edit out the boldness?...

Comment: @TemplateRex Since he needs `unsigned char`, it can't be `std::string` (at least not easily).  But `std::vector<unsigned char>` is definitely the right way to go.

Comment: @Everyone How would I use `std::vector<unsigned char>` instead of `new unsigned char[1024]`? That came from another example. And no this isn't homework :-) Just me trying to expand my `Objective-C` knowledge into `C/C++`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy), from the `algorithm` header:

```
std::copy(hw.begin(), hw.end(), r_record + 10);
```

If you want to use a vector instead of the dynamically allocated array (a good idea), then

```
std::vector<unsigned char> r_record(1024); // 1024 zero initialized elements
std::copy(hw.begin(), hw.end(), r_record.begin() + 10);
```

Comment: Just a quick note: that copies the characters (which is what he seems to be asking about); most binary formats (which is presumably why the buffer of `unsigned char`) also require some means of determining the length.  (Also, of course, he should be using `std::vector<unsigned char>`, and not `new unsigned char[]`.)