# C++ - Copying unsigned char* to a new unsigned char* array

Tags: c++, arrays, opencv, std, unsigned-char

This is a followup question to to the question I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21366739/c-allocate-an-unsigned-char-buffer-and-then-fill-it-with-a-string), although it different enough to warrant posting a new question.

I have a `OpenCV` (`cv::Mat`) matrix variable (which is just an `unsigned char *` of with a known size). I used the answer in the referenced question to copy a `std::string` to my `unsigned char*` array using the code:

```
int initial_offset = 10;
unsigned char *r_record = new unsigned char[1024]();
std::copy(title.begin(), title.end(), r_record + initial_offset);
```

This works as expected. But now I would like to loop through each row of the `cv::Mat` variable and insert those unsigned char values into the same `r_record` array.

I have the code:

```
int data_offset = TITLE_OFFSET + 1;
cv::Mat &img = <from somewhere else>

for (int row=0; row<=img.rows; row++) {
        unsigned char* i_row = img.row(row).data;
        std::copy(???, ???, r_record + data_offset);
        data_offset += img.cols; //This happens to be += 32 in every case that I am using
}
```

But I'm not sure what goes in place of the `???` to reference the `i_row` data.
Can this be done?

Also, apparently using `new unsigned char[1024]()` is a bad idea, but I'm not sure how to replace it with something *not* bad.

**Update:**

Looks like the response from @juanchopanza below isn't quite working.
Here is what I have:

```
std::string = "Title 1";
cv::Mat mat = <from somewhere else>;

//Test case
desc.data[1] = (unsigned char)65;

//Write the image information to the database
unsigned char *image_record = new unsigned char[1024]();
std::copy(title.begin(), title.end(), r_record + title_offset);
std::copy(mat.begin<unsigned char>(), mat.end<unsigned char>(), r_record + 33);
```

**But no matter what, `r_record` only contains: `"Title 1"`. Does anyone have any ideas?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
std::copy(img.begin<unsigned char>(), img.end<unsigned char>(), r_record + data_offset);
```

Comment: With this, is there any reason to loop through each row? It doesn't look like it (which makes this solution better).

Comment: @Brett This would copy the elements as required. No need for loops over rows.

Comment: I'm not getting the expected results. I updated the post with some more of my code. Any ideas?

Comment: How do you check the contents of `r_record`?

Comment: I'm using Xcode as my IDE, and I just do a `print r_record` in the debugger (after setting a breakpoint). Not sure it's ideal, but it does output `"Title 1"` and nothing else.

Comment: @Brett no idea. Check the contents of the `cv::Mat` object. And loop over all `1024` entries of `r_record`, printing out each character.

Comment: Contents are correct in `cv::Mat`. I'm finding an oddity when adding `33` to the index. When I set it to a value less than the length of "Title 1" (ie., less than 7), it works. Over 7 and it doesn't. Would `std::copy()` resize `r_record` after the title insertion?

Comment: @Brett No, copy doesn't resize anything. Just loop over the contents of `r_record` as I said. The problem could be that you have a `0` after `Title 1`, and whatever you are using to print interprets that as the termination of the string.

Comment: Just ran a loop over the 1024 elements. They are all there are expected, so the code works. It's odd that I couldn't see this in Xcode though. Thanks for your input. Answer accepted!